# Adding a value to a cell containing letters and values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add a value (e.g. 1) to a cell that contains both letters and values.

For example:

The original cell contains "quarter 1". In a different cell I want to add a formula that will add "1" to this. So in this example, the outcome would be "quarter 2".

Another example would be "quarter 3" in the original cell, and the formula would return "quarter 4" in the next cell.

I have found lots of examples combining letters and values, but have been unable to find anything that adds "1" to a cell that already contains a combination. Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible? Many thanks!!

Comment: Is the text always going to be in the format "Quarter xx" where xx is the number? If this is quarters of a year, are you expecting 4 + 1 to equal 1?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Yes format will always be "Quarter xx". And yes that's a very good point - "Quarter 4 + 1" would have to return "Quarter 1"

Comment: Going forward you could always give the cell a custom number format of `"Quarter" #`.  The cell will contain just a number that you can add to using a normal formula, but will display `Quarter 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a bit more flexible / allowing input of any number placed in `A2`:

`=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1),1,(RIGHT(A1,1)+A2)-ROUNDDOWN((RIGHT(A1,1)+A2)/4,0)*4),"0","1")`

**Edit**:-
@jkpieterse is right, this makes more sense if you are only going to be adding 1

`="Quarter "&IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="4",1,RIGHT(A1,1)+1)`

Comment: Or ="Quarter "&IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="4",1,RIGHT(A1,1)*1+1)